# Yasnippets won't expand in git-commit-mode?

Tags: magit, yasnippet

I have written a snippet for `git-commit-mode`.  However when I'm writing a commit message (from Magit), the snippet won't trigger.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

I have yasnippet version 20160924.2001, and Emacs 24.5.1.

Comment: See [Eligible snippets](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-expansion.html#sec-2-1), `git-commit-mode` is a minor mode.

Comment: @npostavs, Thank you.  This is strange... Because on some minor mode, Yasnippet does work.  For example I use a minor mode called "beancount" under org-mode, and it works with Yasnippets just fine...

Comment: If you mean your org-mode snippets work just fine, then that's expected. If you mean your beancount snippets work too, then perhaps beancount has some code to enable them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git-commit-mode` is a minor-mode but you have limited the snippets to be used with a major-mode `git-commit-mode`. Such a major-mode no longer exists, so you have to use a different mechanism to restrict your snippets to "when I edit a commit message".

The reason `git-commit-mode` is a minor-mode is to allow you to choose the major-mode most suitable for commit messages according to the conventions used by the projects you contribute to. By default this is `text-mode`, but if some project uses Markdown or Org-Mode for commit messages, then you can configure that on a per project basis.

Assuming you have some snippets that are appropriate for `text-mode`+`git-commit-mode`, but not just `text-mode` or say `markdown-mode`+`git-commit-mode`, then use something like:

```
(add-hook 'git-commit-mode
          (lambda ()
            (when (derived-mode-p 'text-mode)
              (yas-activate-extra-mode 'text-mode+git-commit-mode))))
```

You then have to define your snippets as if there actually existed a major-mode named `text-mode+git-commit-mode`.

Comment: I had to use ```git-commit-setup-hook``` instead of ```git-commit-mode```, as shown [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32983/insert-and-expand-snippet-when-committing-with-magit). Adding a hook to ```git-commit-mode``` somehow caused the standard Magit keybinds to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

By default the major-mode for `git-commit-mode` is `text-mode`, if your `yasnippet` doesn't work in `text-mode`, it won't work in `git-commit-mode` either, so you may want to change it to other mode like `org-mode` using `(setq git-commit-major-mode 'org-mode)`

`org-mode` is my default major-mode for unrecognized files.