# Insert and expand snippet when committing with Magit

Tags: magit, git

I use a template with Git for keeping my commits messages neat and professional, as explained [here](https://gist.github.com/adeekshith/cd4c95a064977cdc6c50).

However, since I use Magit, I would like to insert and expand a snippet with Yasnippets because Yasnippet is more dynamic than a static template.

I would like to know how to trigger the insertion and expansion of a snippet when the buffer for writing the commit message opens in Magit.

Comment: I'm not familiar with yasnippet, but you can add custom setup code to Magit commits via `git-commit-setup-hook`.

Comment: @Basil please make your comment an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magit comes with the minor mode `git-commit-mode`, enabled via the entry-point `global-git-commit-mode`, which runs the hook and user option `git-commit-setup-hook` as its last step. You can add your `git-commit-mode`-specific setup code to this as you would any other hook variable:

```el
(add-hook 'git-commit-setup-hook #'my-git-commit-setup-yasnippet)
```

or

```el
(add-hook 'git-commit-setup-hook
          (lambda ()
            (do-something-with-yasnippet)))
```

You could also use the Customize interface to achieve this via `M-x customize-option RET git-commit-setup-hook RET`. Either way I recommend you look at the documentation and suggested and already enabled hook functions reported by Customize for this hook.

The setup code for `git-commit-mode` also enables an arbitrary major mode which controls the overall editing behaviour for commit messages. This mode is determined by the user option `git-commit-major-mode`. Thus the hook for whichever major mode you specify could offer another means of running custom setup code.